# Media Queries not working properly after Javascript alters element CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media

any idea why in the example below, media queries stops changing the height of the menu bar **after** it's been changed by js? (make window small and click on the arrow to expand the mini menu). Do I need to register a point of origin for the menu element or something?

CSS:

```
#menu {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    z-index: 11000;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #F03600;
    }
```

JS:

```
if ($("#arrowup").css('top') == '0px') {
    $("#menu").animate({'height':'270px'}, 800, "easeInOutQuint");
    } else {
    $("#menu").animate({'height':'55px'}, 800, "easeInOutQuint");
    }
```

You can check out the page here, all the code's on a single page:

http://www.nioute.co.uk/stuff/

Also, what's a good read with regards to media queries / js interaction?

Thanks!

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason the media queries don't work is because when you modify the bar with Javascript, it applies inline-css. This overrides CSS that you may have in your stylesheets. The problem seems to be, when you toggle the arrow back down, `#menu` has an inline style of `height="55px"` applied to it, which blocks the regular style of `90px` on a larger size.

The solution would be to clear the style when the window is resized to larger than your media query breakpoint using something like `$(window).resize(function()...);` and checking the current width of the window against your breakpoint. If it returns true, call `$('#menu').attr('style', '');` and that will remove the inline style.

Comment: Worked really well Andrew thanks. Also instead of **.attr()** I used **document.getElementById("menu").style.height = "90px";** - For extending the script to mobile devices I found matchMedia useful: http://dbaron.org/log/20110422-matchMedia

Answer (score 1):

You can use class for adding some styles to elements and removing they after the job instead of `getElementById(#menu).style.height = ...`

for example:

```
getElementById(#menu).classList.add("newHeight")
```

Or

```
getElementById(#menu).classList.remove("newHeight")
```